# Apt error: File on system created by you or by a script

Tags: apt, dpkg

I have a simple bash script that connects to a series of servers and updates a specific package, using a here-string to answer a prompt:

```
sudo /usr/bin/apt-get install package-name <<< Y
```

The prompt is:

```
Configuration file /etc/package-name/package-name.conf
==> File on system created by you or by a script.
==> File also in package provided by package maintainer.
  What would you like to do about it? Your options are:
  Y or I : install the package maintainer's version
  N or O : keep your currently-installed version
    D    : show the differences between the versions
    Z    : background this process to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** package-name.conf (Y/I/N/O/D/Z [default=N] ?
```

This is the error when it doesn't work:

```
dpkg: error processing package-name (--configure):
EOF on stdin a conffile prompt
Errors were encountered while processing:
package-name
```

I'm not able to install expect or any other programs on the servers. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should pass in a `dpkg` option to specify at the prompt the desired behavior in this scenario.  Then it won't prompt.

```
sudo apt-get -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confnew" -y install package-name
```

(Untested; obtained by googling.)

Comment: This worked, tripleee - thanks. I modified the command to:

`sudo apt-get -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confnew" install package-name`

Comment: For opposite, use: `--force-confold`.

Comment: see also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/104899/make-apt-get-or-aptitude-run-with-y-but-not-prompt-for-replacement-of-configu

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the apt-get man page, you can find an option (-y) to answer yes for you. Why not try that.

Comment: sorry - should have mentioned that I tried that. It doesn't work in this case.

Comment: dpkg: error processing package-name (--configure):
EOF on stdin a conffile prompt
Errors were encountered while processing:
package-name

Comment: you just do `sudo /usr/bin/apt-get install -y package-name` (not tested) without the `<<<`

Comment: `apt-get install -y, --yes, --assume-yes` do not work in this case.

Comment: As an alternative, if you need to answer with a capital Y, or some other string, you could use `yes`. Invoked as `yes`, it will print `y` at all prompts. If `yes <string>`, it will print `<string>` instead.

Comment: The `-y` flags were among the first things I tried; it doesn't even work on the command line in this case. Thanks, though; I know I provided limited info.

Comment: @carlpett Probably don't do that; the reason there's are explicit command-line options to avoid using a pipe from `yes` is that you can't know, in the general case, what you are replying to (it could be asking for your domain name, time zone, database password, etc etc)